# How to download command line tools in xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, command-line

I just installed xcode 4.5 and need to install the command line tools.  The apple documentations says (with very little detail) that there is a download section in the preferences pane.  I have yet to see anywhere that allows you to download anything, specifically the command line tools.

Did Apple change xcode drastically, I do not have a downloads section.

[image]

Comment: That screenshot displays a very old version of XCode. Are you sure you are starting a current version of XCode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Xcode:

Preferences > Downloads > Components

DMG's directly from:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot.  I do not have a downloads tab.  Unless I am looking somewhere wrong....

Comment: @ngramsky I think you are. Click the Xcode menu, go preferences, then go downloads tab, then click the Components subtab. That's what I see here, using 4.5.

Comment: @ngramsky ... your screen shot is weird. I don't know what's up.

Comment: Thanks!  Unsure why the download tab is no longer present.  It seems like Apple is making A LOT of weird changes lately....

Comment: This is the 'new' xcode that was downloaded yesterday....  Version 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

The downloads tab is not available when you open xcode-developer. I found his out by searching in spotlight and noticing two versions could be opened. Open the xcode-main one instead and follow the instructions as above.

Comment: What is Xcode-developer and Xcode-main ? and Xcode is not on version 5

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5.1.1 has a new argument:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/xcode -installComponents
```

Answer (score 0):

For xCode version 5.1.1

Start the **Xcode** program

Select **Xcode** from the top left of the toolbar.

Select **Open Developer Tools** instead of Preferences.

Select **More Developer Tools** at the bottom of the list and it will take you to the Apple Developer Page where you can download the **Command Line Tools**.

---

EDIT: Added a another step to the instructions after reading the post from Garman